# How to improve my coding style for assigning a new value?

Tags: python, pep8

Is there a better way to write the third line of following code ?

```
from datetime import date
d = date.today()
d = d.replace(day=1)
```

Comment: No. Since `.replace` is not in-place and returns a new object there is not much you can do besides making it all a single line as @Pedru demonstrated in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
d = date.today().replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you did it right.

another suggestion:

```
current_date=date.today()
fixed_date=date(current_date.year, current_date.month, 1)
```